# Safari 9 - Label click doesn't fire change event

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

On Safari 9, changing a radio button via its label doesn't fire the alert.
Do you know the reason or a workaround?

HTML

```
<input id="star-1" type="radio" name="question[1]" value="1" required>
<label for="star-1" title="stella 1">
    <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label>
<input id="star-2" type="radio" name="question[1]" value="2" required>
<label for="star-2" title="stella 2">
    <i class="active fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</label>
```

JS

```
var inputRadio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputRadio.length; i++) {
    inputRadio[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
        alert('ciao');
    });
}
```

Comment: maybe attach an onclick aswell?

Comment: @d0n.key to the label itself? I tried, it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works in Safari 9:

```
var inputRadio = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputRadio.length; i++) {
  inputRadio[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    alert('ciao');
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbmk9xL8/1/ - Here's a fiddle to prove it.

Maybe it's some CSS that mess it up?

Comment: A previous script was failing and blocking all the remaining js. Thanks anyway.